# How can I submit to a file in controller from view

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am a new student and I am learning **Codeigniter**. I have a form view and I want to submit name, email, sdt to add.php to check but I can't connect to `add.php.`

This is my form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Form Dang Ky</h2>
<form name="submitbd" action="add.php/check" method="POST">
 Name<br>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="">
      <br>
   Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="">
    <br>
     SDT<br>
    <input type="text" name="sdt" value="">
    <br>
    <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   <br>
 </form> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

and I try to call file add.php in controller, but I got **

> 404 error

Add.php file in controller

```
   <?php
   class Add extends IC_Controller{
    $data = array(
        '$_name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        '$email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        '$sdt'=>$this ->input-> post('sdt')
        );
    public function _contruct(){
        parent::_contruct();
    }
    public function  check(){
        $this->load->database();
        $a=$this->db->query("select email from info where 
    email=.$array($email)");
        if($a==""){
            echo "ok";
        }
        echo "not ok";           
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Your form action is likely not helping, as you are pointing it to add.php/check.  You will likely need to adjust that.

Comment: pls read first https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you**

Your *`form` tag  should be like this :*

```
<form name="submitbd" action="<?=site_url('add/check');?>" method="POST">
..........
</form>
```

*Your Controller* *`Add.php` should be like this :*

```
class Add extends CI_Controller
{
    public function _contruct(){
       parent::_contruct();
       $this->load->database();
       $this->load->helper('url');
    }
    public function  check()
    {
       $_name = $this->input->post('name');
       $email = $this->input->post('email');
       $sdt   = $this->input->post('sdt');
       $sql   = "select email from info where email='{$email}'";
       $query = $this->db->query($sql);
       if($query->num_rows() > 0)
       {
          echo "ok";
       }
       else
       {
          echo "not ok";           
       }
    }
}
```

See for more: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/index.html

Comment: Thank for your answer  but it still have error 404 Page Not Found,
Do i need to change the file config.php or routes.php

Comment: set base_url in your config.php like this  `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_app_folder/';`  and also remove `.htaccess` file from application folder to your your_app_folder